# How do you remove the annoying default border in a Tkinter menu widget (Python 3)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing an app in Tkinter in which I have a menu widget. I changed the background colour of my  menu widget, however, the annoying border color doesn't seem to change. I tried using highlightthickness attribute, but it didn't work out. For reference, here is the code for my menu widget:

```
   menu = tkinter.Menubutton(title_bar, text = "⋮", width = 3, bd = 0, bg = "#E6B905", relief = "flat", pady = 4, activebackground = "#D1A804")
    menu.grid(row = 0, column = 3, padx = 0, sticky = "W")
    CreateToolTip(menu, "Other Options")
    accentItems.append(menu)

    menu.menu = tkinter.Menu(menu, tearoff = 0, bd = 0, relief = "solid", font = "Segoe_UI 9", bg = "#333333", activeborderwidth = 0, activebackground = "#404040", fg = "white", activeforeground = "white", selectcolor = "white")
    menu["menu"] = menu.menu

    menu.menu.add_command(label = "Choose theme:")
    menu.menu.add_radiobutton(label = "Blue", command = accentblue)
    menu.menu.add_radiobutton(label = "Yellow", command = accentyellow)
    menu.menu.add_radiobutton(label = "Green", command = accentgreen)
    menu.menu.add_radiobutton(label = "Pink", command = accentpink)
    menu.menu.add_separator()
    menu.menu.add_command(label = "Open Note", command = openFile)
    menu.menu.add_command(label = "Save Note As", command = saveNoteAs)
    menu.menu.add_command(label = "Save Note", command = saveNote)
    menu.menu.add_separator()
    menu.menu.add_command(label = "Undo", command = Undo)
    menu.menu.add_command(label = "Redo", command = Redo)
    menu.menu.add_command(label = "Quit", command = windowdestroy)
    menu.menu.add_command(label = "Help")
```

And here is a screenshot of the result:
[Click here to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oSdQ.png)

It's that annoying white border I want to remove. Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: You can't remove it (on windows). I built an entire menu system from scratch due to this exact problem. It actually wasn't very hard. I just used a modified `Listbox`.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry Okay, thanks for the tip! Can you share the gist of what you did with the `Listbox`, or the code itsef?

Comment: I subclassed `Listbox` and mirrored all the `Menu` methods with custom logic. For instance, my menu also has an `add_command` method that expects the same arguments, but I wrote all the logic to manage those arguments. Getting it to (dis)appear was done with `place` and `place_forget`. It was like 400 lines of code in total, so pretty tiny and simple. If you think about it, all a menu is, is a bunch of labels that do something when you click them.